# Is there a way to say "download" and "upload" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, new-latin

I checked neolatinlexicon and Google and I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 4):

One possible set of words that would make sense for Latin could be to use *importare* and *exportare*:

- *importare*: to bring, carry, or convey into, to bring in from abroad, to import
- *exportare*: to bear or carry out, to bring out, convey away, export

Both of these are classical words, and the development in meaning is easy enough to tease out. If you really think about it, importing/exporting e.g. an image from an image editing software is really loading it/unloading it, getting that same root as upload/download. Moreover, it will allow for puns on/developments of *porta/portus*.

You'll not likely find a true word for it without resorting to calques. Even Germans often resort to using *[Download](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Download#German)* instead of a calque (for the noun, at least, don't know about the frequency of *downloaden*). I think it's because the English terms, as invented words (the original meaning of "download" is only from 1977 and [changed](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=download) as computing evolved), captured both a basic action *and* a metaphorical one, visualizing "cyberspace" directionally, thus the "up" and "down" prefix. But I think for Latin, *in* and *ex* work equally as well.

Answer (score 2):

Traupman gives *ex rete prehendere*, and *ex rete expromere*. I note that *ex rete prehendere* is findable with a Google search, including some hits to [Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11334/what-should-we-call-a-laptop).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I would assign new meanings to verbs derived from verbs [*mittō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitto#Latin) ("to send") or [*ferō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fero#Latin) ("to bear, carry") with prefixes [*super-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/super-#Latin) and [*sub-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub-#Latin):

[*supermittō*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/supermitto#Latin): "to upload"

[*superferō*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/superfero#Latin): "to upload"

[*summittō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summitto#Latin): "to download"

[*sufferō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suffero#Latin): "to download"

Compare verbs [*trānsmittō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transmitto#Latin) ("to transmit, send, carry, or convey across, over or through") and [*trānsferō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transfero#Latin) ("to bear, carry or bring across or over; transport, transfer, convey over").

Comment: If only "submit" wasn't associated with the meaning "upload" in English... I think using "summitto" for "to download" can easily lead to a confusion.

Comment: @FlatAssembler
I added alternative idea with *ferō*. Let's suffer more :) .

Comment: @FlatAssembler One issue with that though is that Latin can easily be confused with English already. Think about the meanings of *sententia* or the difference between *opportunitas* and *occasio*. There's no good reason to let English dictate what the Latin ought to be.